# NHibernate querying with WHERE conditions in pairs

Tags: linq, nhibernate

I have a collection of NHibernate objects `ConcurrentBag<Event>` with properties `project_id` and `name`. I want to a set of unrelated (schema wise) objects from another table which also match these properties.

The SQL I would expect would look something like:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (project_id = 1 AND name = 'foo') 
    OR (project_id = 2 AND name = 'foo') 
    OR (project_id = 1 AND name = 'bar') 
    ... etc
```

The pairs of values in the WHERE clause are based on the values from each `Event` in the `ConcurrentBag<Event>`.

I am not sure how to query this with NHibernate (ideally with LINQ). Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be difficult with LINQ I think, but if you use QueryOver it's easy to build a `WHERE` clause dynamically using `Restrictions.Disjunction`:

```
var disjunction = Restrictions.Disjunction();

foreach (Event evt in events)
{
    disjunction.Add(Restrictions.Where<Table>(
        t => t.project_id == evt.project_id && t.name == evt.name);
}

var rows = session.QueryOver<Table>()
    .Where(disjunction)
    .List<Table>();
```

Comment: If the values were literal sure, but I don't know how I get from an `IEnumerable` of values to generate that Where(...) filter. Maybe that wasn't clear from the question, I will update.

Comment: @AndySavage: Updated--using QueryOver this might be easier than LINQ.